# Start .bat file via php

Tags: php, git, batch-file, cmd.exe, exec

I'm using
`system('START C:\[address]\refresh.bat');`
but when I start this I get:

```
C:\[address]>git fetch
'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How to fix this problem?

I tried shell_exec and adding to PATH

> C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\ and
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\

I need a button on my site, that will fetch and pull the changes from my repository.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error "'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492979/error-git-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: You need to restart the service after changing PATH.

Comment: shingo, you mean restart the pc with host?

Comment: still not working

Comment: I solved this by chose "My Path + Win Path" in setiings of OSPanel

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by chose "My Path + Win Path" in setiings of OSPanel.

[image]